# Yii2 как из другой модели передать в форму данные в инпут

Tags: yii2

Привет всем.

Есть две таблицы, Profile там у меня хранятся имя, телефон, город, улица и.т.д, в другой таблицы Orders есть name, phone, city, street.

Я делаю ActiveForm и хотел бы подтянуть в поля где имя, телефон, город, улица в input name, phone, city, street, а потом происходило сохранения в orders.

я не могу понять как мне это сделать??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

получи данные в экшине контроллера и передай их в нем в форму, в форме добавь нужные поля подставив нужные значения и при сохранении провалидируй форму там же в экшине и сохрани.

примерно

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $order = Order::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $order->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $order->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'order' => $order,
        ]);
    }
}
```

и в форме поля

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>

<?= $form->field($order, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```